# ¿ Como obtener un array de solo cierta información ? => PHP

Tags: php, array, bucles

me encuentro realizando un proceso para el cual quiero que mi resultado sea así

```
Array(
[0] => 34343
[1] => 6757
[2] => 12324
)
```

Para eso tengo esta función que estoy haciendo:

```
public function extraer_imagenes_secciones()
{
    //LLamo al modelo
    $obj_informacion = new InformacionPaginaPrincipal();
    // esta variable obtiene todas las tablas de las secciones en total son 7
    $secciones = $obj_informacion->secciones_all();
    // declaro un array vacio
    $datos = array();
    //Recorro todas las 7 secciones
    foreach ($secciones as $value) {
        /*esta variable obtengo todos los campos de la tabla de la seccion que  
          esta siendo recorrida*/
        $data_tabla = $obj_informacion->mostrar_seccion_dinamica($value->nombre_seccion);
        // pregunto que si tabla seccion se llama de esta forma
        if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_examinar_hoja') {
            // Agrego el valor del campo size_documento a un array
            $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
        }
        if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_informacion') {
            $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
        }
        if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_plataforma') {
            $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($datos);
    } // End foreach
} // End function extraer_imagenes_secciones
```

De esta forma quiero que los valores del campo `size_documento` en cada tabla se agreguen a un solo array y no me devuelva como lo está haciendo en estos momentos con ese bloque de codigo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo solo necesitas agregar un print_r($datos) despues del foreach, ya que el var_dump() te esta imprimiendo varias veces el arreglo.
lo demás se ve todo bien. exito!

```
public function extraer_imagenes_secciones()    
{
//LLamo al modelo
$obj_informacion = new InformacionPaginaPrincipal();
// esta variable obtiene todas las tablas de las secciones en total son 7
$secciones = $obj_informacion->secciones_all();
// declaro un array vacio
$datos = array();
//Recorro todas las 7 secciones
foreach ($secciones as $value) {
    /*esta variable obtengo todos los campos de la tabla de la seccion que  
      esta siendo recorrida*/
    $data_tabla = $obj_informacion->mostrar_seccion_dinamica($value->nombre_seccion);
    // pregunto que si tabla seccion se llama de esta forma
    if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_examinar_hoja') {
        // Agrego el valor del campo size_documento a un array
        $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
    }
    if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_informacion') {
        $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
    }
    if ($value->nombre_seccion === 'informacion_contenido_plataforma') {
        $datos[] = $data_tabla[0]->size_documento;
    }

    echo '<pre>';        
    } // End foreach
   print_r($datos);
    } // End function extraer_imagenes_secciones
```

Comment: Hola amigo, realmente me diste la luz! claro es evidente que el var_dump que tenia en mi código estaba dentro del ciclo. Muchas gracias por ayudarme a resolver el error